# How to export multiple variables to csv?

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to export two variables into separate columns of a csv. Both variables have the same number of strings.

Example:

```
$1 has 1,2,3,4
$2 has 7,8,9,10
```

I want the csv to look like the following:

```
col1   col2
1      7
2      8
3      9
4      10
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do this trick:

```
$arr = @()
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $1.length; $i++) {
    $obj = new-object psobject
    $obj = Add-Member -inp $obj col1 $1[$i] -PassThru
    $obj = Add-Member -inp $obj col2 $2[$i] -PassThru
    $arr += $obj
}
$arr | Export-Csv $home\foo.csv
```

If you are on V3, you can simplify this to:

```
$arr = @()
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $1.length; $i++) {
    $arr += [pscustomobject]@{col1=$1[$i];col2=$2[$i]}
}
$arr | Export-Csv $home\foo.csv
```